# Rails: Querying with an Array

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following method which creates and then executes an SQL query:

```
def edition_authors(edition, authors)
  query_string = "contributor_type = ? AND author = ?"
  for i in 1..authors.length - 1
    query_string += " OR author = ?"
  end
  return edition.contributors.where(query_string, 'Author', authors)
end
```

The last line is the one I'm having trouble with. I want the 'authors' array to somehow turn into a set of strings. For instance, if the authors array contained ['James Joyce', 'Cory Doctorow', 'Cormac McCarthy'], I'd like that last line to read like:

```
return edition.contributors.where(query_string, 'Author', 'James Joyce', 'Cory Doctorow', 'Cormac McCarthy')
```

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends which rails and which ruby you are using,

1. ActiveRecord already has this functionality in Rails 3: `Model.where(:my_field => ['Author', 'James Joyce', 'Cory Doctorow', 'Cormac McCarthy'])`
2. `arr.map{|v| v.to_s.inspect}` will get you a comma separated list
3. `arr.join(',')` will give you a comma separated list, no quotes.

Then you can use this string however you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Instead of using a big bunch of `OR`s, use a SQL `IN` clause, and
2. then use [`Array#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join) to supply the values

So:

```
.where("contributor_type = ? AND author IN (?)", 'Author', authors.join("','"))
```

should do the trick, with some caveats: string values in a SQL IN clause need to be single quoted and comma separated `SELECT * FROM fubar WHERE blah IN ('foo','bar','baz');` I think Rails is clever about knowing how to quote things, so look in the Rails log to see what SQL is being generated if you're getting an error.

Also, since your values may contain single quotes (Georgia O'Keefe) I am not sure if Rails is smart enough to escape these for you when used in this manner.

Bonus tip: make sure there's an index on the `Author` column.  This is an *expensive* query, in general.

Comment: Aw snap!  @Michael's answer is much better than mine.  Rails is so cool, of course there's a simple way :-).

Comment: your join is missing the beginning and end single quotes, you would need to add them in.

Comment: Actually, that was "hopefully intentional" which is what I was implying by "Rails is clever..." -- you don't need to quote strings when used in a placeholder.  But yeah, if I am wrong, the IN clause would be `...IN ('?')...` or maybe the value would need to be something horrific like `"'#{authors.join("','")}'"`, which leads me to my comment, that your answer is better all around :-)